# Someone ate my porridge

Tags: grammar

> Someone has **been** eating my porridge.

Is it same with *Someone ate my porridge.*

Comment: No. Someone *ate* means the porridge was eaten all up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Someone ***has been*** eating my porridge

This means the procedure is going on. Either the glutton is eating it piece by piece stealthily or over a period of time. Say, you kept your porridge in a refrigerator and you observe that daily, it gets eaten! You may then express your annoyance that way.

On the other hand,

> Someone ***ate*** my porridge - shows *poor* state of yours!

I mean you are helpless now...as the porridge is *already* eaten. It's finished and you cannot do anything.